# Exclude .svn directories from grep

Tags: linux, bash, svn, grep

When I grep my Subversion working copy directory, the results include a lot of files from the .svn directories. Is it possible to recursively grep a directory, but exclude all results from  .svn directories?

Comment: Related [How can I exclude directories from grep -R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565471/how-can-i-exclude-directories-from-grep-r)

Answer (score 274, accepted):

If you have GNU Grep, it should work like this:

```
grep --exclude-dir=".svn"
```

If happen to be on a Unix System without GNU Grep, try the following:

```
grep -R "whatever you like" *|grep -v "\.svn/*"
```

Comment: On the Windows version of GNU Grep, I had to use `--exclude-dir=\.svn`

Comment: Only for gnu grep version >=2.5.1a

Comment: ha. I was just about to upvote but I had already. seems I was here before :)

Comment: +1 for the second example, the first didn't work for me with GNU grep 2.6.3 using `export GREP_OPTIONS="--exclude-dir=\".svn\" -nR --color"`

Comment: `alias grepsvn='grep --exclude-dir=".svn"'`
`grepsvn -R searchstring .`

Comment: As @osgx said, `exclude-dir` doesn't work on my GNU grep 2.5. Instead, the following works well for me as all the accidental matches are within the *.svn-base files: `grep --exclude="*.svn-base"`

Comment: Was doing it the latter way, but that lost `--color` support, which made me sad. `--exclude-dir` gets me what I need, and color-coded.

Comment: An alias to exclude **all** dot-starting dirs: `alias grepexclhid="grep --exclude-dir=\".*\""`. One might even want to make the alias name to be `grep`, then to use it without an alias you'd have to type full path `/usr/bin/grep`.

Answer (score 40):

For grep >=2.5.1a

You can put this into your environment (e.g. `.bashrc`)

```
export GREP_OPTIONS='--exclude-dir=".svn"'
```

PS: thanks to Adrinan, there are extra quotes in my version:

```
export GREP_OPTIONS='--exclude-dir=.svn'
```

PPS: This env option is marked for deprecation: https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Environment-Variables.html "*As this causes problems when writing portable scripts, this feature will be removed in a future release of grep, and grep warns if it is used. Please use an alias or script instead.*"

Comment: You don't need to have double quote - it didnt work for me when the double quote is present

Comment: GREP_OPTIONS stopped being a supported environment variable after 2.20

Answer (score 36):

If you use [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) (a 'better grep') it will handle this automatically (and do a lot of other clever things too!). It's well worth checking out.

Comment: +1 for ack. I have a shell alias and use it by default.

Comment: Really nice that ack. Careful that, in Ubuntu and Linux Mint, the "ack" package has nothing to do with the "ack - better grep", which is located in the "ack-grep" package.

Comment: That unfortunately didn't solve problem with *all* hidden dirs *(e.g. I don't want it to descend to `.stack-work` dir)*, also I didn't quite like that its output takes more space by having filenames on a separate line. So I end up making an alias to grep `alias grepexclhid="grep --exclude-dir=\".*\""`.

Answer (score 7):

psychoschlumpf is correct, but it only works if you have the latest version of `grep`.  Earlier versions do not have the `--exclude-dir` option.  However, if you have a very large codebase, double-`grep`-ing can take forever.  Drop this in your `.bashrc` for a portable `.svn`-less grep:

```
alias sgrep='find . -path "*/.svn" -prune -o -print0 | xargs -0 grep'
```

Now you can do this:

```
sgrep some_var
```

... and get expected results.

Of course, if you're an insane person like me who just *has* to use the same `.bashrc` everywhere, you could spend 4 hours writing an overcomplicated bash function to put there instead.  *Or*, you could just wait for an insane person like me to post it online:

http://gist.github.com/573928

Comment: The method you list above using find and xargs does not work, at least on RHEL5 in my environment. I still get .svn-base listings.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep --exclude-dir=".svn"
```

works because the name ".svn" is rather unique. But this might fail on a more generalized name.

```
grep --exclude-dir="work"
```

is not bulletproof, if you have "/home/user/work" and "/home/user/stuff/work" it will skip both. It is not possible to define "/*/work/*" 
 to restrict the exclusion to only the former folder name.
As far as I could experiment, in GNU grep the simple --exclude won't exclude directories.

Comment: Only for gnu grep version >=2.5.1a

Comment: This should be a comment to the accepted answer, not an answer in itself.

Comment: @Dave: Thanks for the tip. You have just commented on a 2 year old comment.

Answer (score 2):

On my GNU grep 2.5, `--exclude-dirs` is not a valid option. As an alternative, this worked well for me:

```
grep --exclude="*.svn-base"
```

This should be a better solution than excluding all lines which contain `.svn/` since it wouldn't accidentally filter out such lines in a real file.

Comment: Have you noticed difference, this is `--exclude-dir` no `--exclude-dirs`?

Answer (score 1):

Two greps will do the trick:

1. The first grep will get everything.
2. The second grep will use output of first grep as input (via piping).  By using the -v flag, grep will select the lines which DON'T match the search terms.  Voila.  You are left with all the ouputs from the first grep which do not contain .svn in the filepath.

   -v, --invert-match
         Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.

   ```
   grep the_text_you_want_to_search_for * | grep -v .svn
   ```

Comment: The second grep removes all color formatting.

Comment: Another problem is that it will remove any lines that happen to have ".svn" in them, whether or not the .svn is because of the filename, or is actually in the file.  Another problem is that you're spending the time searching the files in the .svn directory that you know you're going to exclude.  Better to --exclude from the beginning.

Comment: This would also waste time finding matches in .svn only to filter them after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

I tried double grep'in on my huge code base and it took forever so I got this solution with the help of my co-worker

Pruning is much faster as it stops find from processing those directories compared to 'grep -v' which processes everything and only excludes displaying results

```
find . -name .svn -prune -o -type f -print0 | xargs -0 egrep 'YOUR STRING'
```

You can also alias this command in your .bashrc as

```
alias sgrep='find . -name .svn build -prune -o -type f -print0 | xargs -0 egrep '
```

Now simply use

```
sgrep 'whatever'
```

Answer (score 0):

For grep version 2.5.1 you can add multiple `--exclude` items to filter out the `.svn` files.

```
$ grep -V | grep grep
grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1

GREP_OPTIONS="--exclude=*.svn-base --exclude=entries --exclude=all-wcprops" grep -l -R  whatever ./
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, albeit one that may not be perceived as an *acceptable* answer is to clone the repo into git and use `git grep`.

Rarely, I run into svn repositories that are so massive, it's just impractical to clone via `git-svn`. In these rare cases, I use a double grep solution, [svngrep](https://github.com/quickshiftin/svngrep/blob/master/svngrep.sh), but as many answers here indicate, this could be slow on large repositories, and exclude '.svn' occurrences that aren't directories. I would argue that these would be extremely seldom though...

Also regarding slow performance of multiple greps, once you've used something like git, pretty much everything seems slow in svn!

One last thing.., my variation of svngrep passes through colorization, beware, the implementation is ugly! Roughly `grep -rn "$what" $where | egrep -v "$ignore" | grep --color "$what"`

Answer (score -1):

I think the --exclude option of recursion is what you are searching for.

Comment: `--exclude` only matches file patterns, like `*.java`