# How can I exclude directories from grep -R?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I want to traverse all subdirectories, except the `node_modules` directory.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/q/66715/59933

Comment: If you are grepping for code in a git repository and `node_modules` is in your `.gitignore`, `git grep "STUFF"` is the easiest way. `git grep` searches the tracked files in the working tree, ignoring everything from `.gitignore`

Comment: An example for node: `grep -R  --exclude-dir={node_modules,bower_components} "MyString" | cut -c1-"$COLUMNS"` -- further you could always alias this in the shell to 'nodegrep' or whatever and use a command argument as string input..

Answer (score 618, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1 (combine `find` and `grep`)**

The purpose of this solution is not to deal with `grep` performance but to show a portable solution : should also work with busybox or GNU version older than 2.5.

Use **`find`**, for excluding directories foo and bar :

```
find /dir \( -name foo -prune \) -o \( -name bar -prune \) -o -name "*.sh" -print
```

Then combine **`find`** and the non-recursive use of **`grep`**, as a portable solution :

```
find /dir \( -name node_modules -prune \) -o -name "*.sh" -exec grep --color -Hn "your text to find" {} 2>/dev/null \;
```

**SOLUTION 2 (using the `--exclude-dir` option of `grep`):**

You know this solution already, but I add it since it's the most recent and efficient solution. Note this is a less portable solution but more human-readable.

```bash
grep -R --exclude-dir=node_modules 'some pattern' /path/to/search
```

To exclude multiple directories, use `--exclude-dir` as:

`--exclude-dir={node_modules,dir1,dir2,dir3}`

**SOLUTION 3 (Ag)**

If you frequently search through code, [Ag (The Silver Searcher)](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) is a much faster alternative to grep, that's customized for searching code. For instance, it automatically ignores files and directories listed in `.gitignore`, so you don't have to keep passing the same cumbersome exclude options to `grep` or `find`.

Comment: this combination searches faster than `--exclude-dir=dir` and it shows results with colors - easy to read

Comment: "this combination" `find ... -exec` is not faster than `grep --exclude-dir` for me. Huge advantage to grep (about five times faster with 26k+ files, filtered out of 38k+ on an HDD), unless you replace the `\;` with `+` for the find/exec combo. Then grep is "only" about 30% faster. The grep syntax is also human-readble :).

Comment: Agreed, since this is obvious. Some busyboxes does not have the GREP command.

Comment: `grep --exclude-dir=dir -rin "text" .` works fine for me. `ag text .` (silver_searcher) works superb

Comment: also noting that you can exclude multiple with `--exclude-dir={dir1,dir2}`

Comment: I'm not the least bit surprised that `node_modules` is the canonical example.

Comment: grep -nr would add line number of match to the results

Comment: Don't add spaces after commas  in `--exclude-dir={dir1,dir2}`

Answer (score 1383):

Recent versions of [**GNU Grep**](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/) (>= [2.5.2](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/commit/?id=29b030df)) provide:

```
--exclude-dir=dir
```

which excludes directories matching the pattern `dir` from recursive directory searches.

So you can do:

```bash
grep -R --exclude-dir=node_modules 'some pattern' /path/to/search
```

For a bit more information regarding syntax and usage see

- The GNU man page for [File and Directory Selection](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/File-and-Directory-Selection.html)
- A related StackOverflow answer [Use grep --exclude/--include syntax to not grep through certain files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/221921/78845)

For older GNU Greps and [**POSIX Grep**](http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/1/grep/), use `find` as suggested in other answers.

Or just use [**`ack`**](http://betterthangrep.com/) (**Edit**: or [**The Silver Searcher**](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher)) and be done with it!

Comment: @Manocho: If you think `ack` is great, try The Silver Searcher and see the speed increase!

Comment: Syntax for the impatient: `--exclude-dir=dir` uses `grep`'s regular expression patterns, _not_ shell's file globbing. Patterns work on paths relative to your current directory. So use pattern `--exclude-dir=dir`, not `--exclude-dir="/root/dir/*"`.

Comment: Note if your grep doesn't support it, you can use `ggrep`

Comment: If you wish to exclude multiple dirs from the search, is there a better option than to use : `$ grep -r --exclude-dir=dir1 --exclude-dir=dir2 "string" /path/to/search/dir` ?

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary: What do you mean by 'better'? That looks like a good approach to me.

Comment: @Johnsyweb, I was hoping for something where I did not have to mention `--exclude-dir` multiple times.

Comment: Unfortunately the default grep comes with OS X 10.11 is still 2.5.1

Comment: @TylerLong: I use `grep` from homebrew-dupes: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/blob/master/grep.rb

Comment: I probably spent way too much time on this than any sane person, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to exclude a subdirectory from the search - `grep -r --exclude-dir=public keyword .` works, but `grep -r --exclude-dir='public/dist' keyword .` does not. I tried adding regex wildcards, escaping characters etc, but nothing seems to help.

Comment: Exclude multiple directories like so: `grep -r "Request" . --exclude-dir={node_modules,git,build}`

Comment: Is there a way to add this to all grep commands I make so I don't need to manually type it every time?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst: You could wrap `grep` in an alias or script.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst you can make an alias as suggested or export it using  GREP_OPTIONS (or a similar) variable I believe. I prefer the alias route in case I really do need to search in one of the excluded directories or with different options I can just bypass the alias.

Comment: @dragon788: `GREP_OPTIONS` is deprecated: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/commit/?id=50d843674e5df9f5d0111f07bbff8ce07c19df6a

Comment: @dkobozev to exclude specific subdirectories you must start with the dot, so using `grep -r --exclude-dir='./public/dist' keyword` should be what you're looking for

Comment: Don't use the relative path, i.e. just `--exclude-dir=dir_name` instead of `--exclude-dir=folder/dir_name` which won't do the desired filtering.

Comment: Would someone mind to explain this a little better? I need to exclude directories that are not subdirectories of the one I'm searching from. Say I write my `grep` command in `~/` and I need to exclude `/media` from the search. I don't think just writing `--exclude-dir=media` would do the trick, because it's not a subdirectory of `~/`. Am I wrong? Should I just `cd` into `/` (it seems odd to me)?

Comment: @dkobozev I couldn't get it to work either. Had to use the following workaround instead:
`grep -r keyword | grep -v 'public/dist'`

Comment: Don't add spaces after commas in `--exclude-dir={dir1,dir2}`

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I use `EXCLUDE_NODEMODULES="--exclude-dir=node_modules --exclude-dir=.git"` in my .bashrc. So I use the same command every time (grep), but I type fast `grep $EXC<tab> -r ...`  which is completed by bash to `grep --exclude... -r ...`

Answer (score 125):

If you want to exclude **multiple directories**:

*"r" for recursive, "l" to print only names of files containing matches and "i" to ignore case distinctions :*

```sh
grep -rli --exclude-dir={dir1,dir2,dir3} keyword /path/to/search
```

*Example : I want to find files that contain the word 'hello'. I want to search in all my linux directories **except** **proc** directory, **boot** directory, **sys** directory and **root** directory :*

```sh
grep -rli --exclude-dir={proc,boot,root,sys} hello /
```

***Note : The example above needs to be root***

***Note 2 (according to @skplunkerin) : do not add spaces after the commas in*** `{dir1,dir2,dir3}`

Comment: **NOTE:** do not add spaces after the commas in `{dir1,dir2,dir3}`

Comment: Thanks, handy when grep'ing through SVN workspace: `grep -Irsn --exclude-dir=.svn 'foo' .`

Comment: You can just provide the `--exclude-dir` option multiple times.

Answer (score 123):

This syntax

```
--exclude-dir={dir1,dir2}
```

is expanded by the shell (e.g. Bash), not by `grep`, into this:

```
--exclude-dir=dir1 --exclude-dir=dir2
```

Quoting will prevent the shell from expanding it, so this won't work:

```
--exclude-dir='{dir1,dir2}'    <-- this won't work
```

The patterns used with `--exclude-dir` are the same kind of patterns described in the man page for the `--exclude` option:

```
--exclude=GLOB
    Skip files whose base name matches GLOB (using wildcard matching).
    A file-name glob can use *, ?, and [...]  as wildcards, and \ to
    quote a wildcard or backslash character literally.
```

The shell will generally *try* to expand such a pattern itself, so to avoid this, you should quote it:

```bash
--exclude-dir='dir?'
```

You can use the curly braces and quoted exclude patterns together like this:

```bash
--exclude-dir={'dir?','dir??'}
```

Answer (score 31):

If you are grepping for code in a git repository and `node_modules` is in your `.gitignore`, you can use `git grep`. `git grep` searches the tracked files in the working tree, ignoring everything from `.gitignore`

```bash
git grep "STUFF"
```

Comment: This is an incredible way to limit wading through tons of generated files (dist, bin, etc.) and it pipes into a utility like `less` automagically so you have a scrollable search result. Fantastic!

Answer (score 23):

Many correct answers have been given here, but I'm adding this one to emphasize one point which caused some rushed attempts to fail before: `exclude-dir` takes a *pattern*, not a path to a directory.

Say your search is:

```
grep -r myobject
```

And you notice that your output is cluttered with results from the `src/other/objects-folder`. This command will *not* give you the intended result:

```
grep -r myobject --exclude-dir=src/other/objects-folder
```

And you may wonder why `exclude-dir` isn't working! To actually exclude results from the `objects-folder`, simply do this:

```
grep -r myobject --exclude-dir=objects-folder
```

In other words, just use the *folder name*, not the path. Obvious once you know it.

From the man page:

> --exclude-dir=GLOB
>          Skip any command-line directory with a name suffix  that  matches  the  pattern  GLOB.   When
>          searching  recursively,  skip  any  subdirectory  whose  base  name matches GLOB.  Ignore any
>          redundant trailing slashes in GLOB.

Comment: Why on the planet didn't I scroll down to this answer before I posted my comment/question up above? I unfortunately have the bad habit to ignore answers with less upvotes, but this explains what I was doing wrong, so thanks Nagev.

Comment: I would go crazy because I used the full path to a subfolder, but it did not work. After I saw this comment, I used the folder name ONLY and it finally worked! THANKS

Answer (score 17):

**Frequently use this:**

`grep` can be used in conjunction with `-r` (recursive), `i` (ignore case) and `-o` (prints only matching part of lines). To exclude `files` use `--exclude` and to exclude directories use `--exclude-dir`.

Putting it together you end up with something like:

```
grep -rio --exclude={filenames comma separated} \
--exclude-dir={directory names comma separated} <search term> <location>
```

Describing it makes it sound far more complicated than it actually is. Easier to illustrate with a simple example.

**Example:**

Suppose I am searching for current project for all places where I explicitly set the string value `debugger` during a debugging session, and now wish to review / remove.

I write a script called `findDebugger.sh` and use `grep` to find all occurrences. However:

For file exclusions - I wish to ensure that `.eslintrc` is ignored (this actually has a linting rule about `debugger` so should be excluded). Likewise, I don't want my own script to be referenced in any results.

For directory exclusions - I wish to exclude `node_modules` as it contains lots of libraries that do reference `debugger` and I am not interested in those results. Also I just wish to omit `.idea` and `.git` hidden directories because I don't care about those search locations either, and wish to keep the search performant.

So here is the result - I create a script called `findDebugger.sh` with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
grep -rio --exclude={.eslintrc,findDebugger.sh} \
--exclude-dir={node_modules,.idea,.git} debugger .
```

Comment: I believe the "r" option should be printed with an upper case "-R".

Comment: Interesting. "r" has always worked for me on nix and mac.

Comment: When I wrote [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8692318/78845), I used `-R` (I don't recall why now). I typically use `-r`. It turns out that the uppercase version [follows symlinks](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/grep.c#n1968). TIL.

Comment: @Johnsyweb - thanks. upvoted your answer - don't recall when, likely in 2016 when I added this one :)

Answer (score 6):

You could try something like `grep -R search . | grep -v '^node_modules/.*'`

Comment: Not such a good solution in some cases.  
For example: If 'node_modules' directory is a huge one with lots of false positive matches (hence the need to filter out the directory) then the first grep is wasting a lot of time searching through a sub-directory and THEN the second grep filtering out the matches. It's faster to exclude node_modules in the first grep itself.

Comment: i don't care about the slowness, I can look at the command and know what it does

Comment: Ditto for Guru's comment. A grep of `/var` hangs when it hits `/var/run` in my case. Hence the reason I want to avoid the directory in the first place.

Comment: `--exclude-dir` is the best solution as of 2016.

Answer (score 4):

Very useful, especially for those dealing with [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) where we want to avoid searching inside "node_modules":

```bash
find ./ -not -path "*/node_modules/*" -name "*.js" | xargs grep keyword
```

Answer (score 3):

Step 1:

`vim ~/.bash_profile`

```bash
search() {
    grep -InH -r --exclude-dir=*build* -e "$1" .
}
```

Step 2:

`source ~/.bash_profile`

Usage:

`search "<string_to_be_searched>"`

Answer (score 2):

A simple working command:

```
root/dspace# grep -r --exclude-dir={log,assetstore} "creativecommons.org"
```

Above I grep for text "creativecommons.org" in current directory "dspace" and exclude dirs {log,assetstore}.

Done.

Comment: Neat, including several directories in brackets

Comment: This was already mentioned in [three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48372385/6243352) [existing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38037037/6243352) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36776063/6243352). Suggest deletion to clean up this thread and remove noise/redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . ! -name "node_modules" -type d
```

Answer (score -1):

This one works for me:

```
grep <stuff> -R --exclude-dir=<your_dir>
```

Comment: How is this answer different from what has already been posted?

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution:

4.1

for i in {1..10}; do openssl rand -base64 6 | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | head -c 8 >> best_secrets.txt && echo >> best_secrets.txt; done

4.2

#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
echo "Usage: $0 "
exit 1
fi

dd if=/dev/urandom of="$1" bs=1M count=150

4.3

alias change_me='chsh -s $(which zsh)'

4.4

#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
echo "Usage: $0 "
exit 1
fi

grep "^$1:" /etc/shadow | cut -d':' -f2

1

Here is my solution:

4.1

```
awk -F: '$3 > 1000 {print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

4.2

```
sudo useradd uso
echo "uso:fancy-password" | sudo chpasswd
```

4.3

```
sort -t: -k7,7 -k3,3n /etc/passwd
```

4.4

```
free -h | grep Mem | awk '{print $4}'
```

2

Answer (score -6):

A simpler way would be to filter your results using "grep -v".

`grep -i needle -R * | grep -v node_modules`

Comment: This is effectively the same answer DipSwitch provided 3 years earlier. It has the same problems, too.