# String Search: Using find / grep, While Ignoring .git and Other Directories

Tags: command-line, grep, find

I often need to search for a particular string from a directory that has git directory `.git/`. This is the command I use:

```
find . -name .git -prune -o -print | xargs grep <string-to-search>
```

The `-name .git -prune -o -print` option is to ignore the files under `.git/`. However, it outputs a lot of *'Is a directory'* messages that clutter the whole result. For example,

```
...
grep: ./reports: Is a directory
grep: ./scripts: Is a directory
grep: ./scripts/js: Is a directory
grep: ./scripts/js/adapter: Is a directory
...
```

How to modify the command line so that I can ignore the `.git/` directory *and* all other directories (i.e. only search the searchable files).

Apparently, the `-type f` option doesn't work well in:

```
find -type f . -name .git -prune -o -print
```

Comment: Why aren't you using [`git-grep`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-grep.html)?

Comment: Also, that last command should be `find . -type f -name .git -prune -o -print`.

Comment: Thanks, @Johnsyweb. `find . -type f -name .git -prune -o -print` actually still outputs directories.

Comment: You're right -- it's so much simpler using `git-grep`: `git grep --untracked <string-to-search>`. Let me keep this question open; I am still curious how we'd do this using the combination of _grep_ and _find_.

Comment: What if you have multiple .git cloned from various places (example using [repo](https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html)), can `git-grep` (or some other tool) handle this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You don't require find command. You can use grep to search in directory. 
You can ignore directory by using exclude-dir syntax.

```
grep -r --exclude-dir=".git;.svn" "string to search" <directory>
```

Comment: N.B: This requires [GNU Grep (>= 2.5.2)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8692318/78845).

Comment: Any alternative for a `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`? Thanks!

Comment: find . -not -iwholename '*.git*'

Comment: add an intermediate "anit-grep" to the pipeline, i.e. `grep -r ... | egrep -v '\.svn|\.git' | .....` Good luck to all.

Comment: This did not work for me with ; delimited paths. Try a single directory if you have any problems

Comment: Upvoted because this works well with multiple .git repositories when using [repo](https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html). However, I had to split the `;` file delimiter like so: `grep -R --exclude-dir=".git" --exclude-dir=".svn" MyRegex`

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question here (without giving any votes, etc.):

Since I was essentially doing a search specifically in a `git`-tracked directory, `git grep` is apparently much simpler and more apt tool for the job. Thanks to @Johnsyweb who initially brought this up!

I chose Vivek's answer because it provides a general `grep` solution as asked in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you try `ripgrep` https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep

> ripgrep is a line-oriented search tool that recursively searches the current directory for a
> regex pattern. By default, ripgrep will respect gitignore rules and
> automatically skip hidden files/directories and binary files.

It's faster and more developer friendly then other tools out there (that I've encountered) including `grep` and `find`

Answer (score -1):

The -type f is misplaced.  It is filtering out directories before the -prune, which expects a directory name. The command should be `find .  -name .git -prune -o -type f -print`.  If you just want grep to shut up about directories, you can set the environment variable `GREP_OPTIONS='--directories=skip'`