# bash function grep --exclude-dir not working

Tags: bash, grep, find

I have the following function defined in my .bashrc, but for some reason the --exclude-dir option is not excluding the .git directory.  Can anyone see what I've done wrong?  I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 if that helps.

```
function fif # find in files
{
  pattern=${1?"  Usage: fif <word_pattern> [files pattern]"};
  files=${2:+"-iname \"$2\""};

  grep "$pattern" --color -n -H -s $(find . $files -type f) --exclude-dir=.git --exclude="*.min.*"
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `--exclude-dir` option is only available in recent versions of GNU grep (>= 2.5.2) - [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8692318/526471). You may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6565519/526471) helpful

Comment: Isn't `--exclude-dir`  supposed to be used in conjunction with `-r` (recursive) ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do a `man grep` on your system, and see what version you have. Your version of grep may not be able to use `--exclude-dirs`.

You're really better off using `find` to find the files you want, then use `grep` to parse them:

```
$ find . -name '.git' -type d -prune \
     -o -name "*.min.*" -prune \
     -o -type f -exec grep --color -n -H {} "$pattern" \;
```

I'm not a fan of the recursive `grep`. Its syntax has become bloated, and it's really unnecessary. We have a perfectly good tool for finding files that match a particular criteria, thank you.

In the `find` program, the `-o` separate out the various clauses. If a file has not been filtered out by a previous `-prune` clause, it is passed to the next one. Once you've pruned out all of the `.git` directories and all of the `*.min.*` files, you pass the results to the `-exec` clause that executes your grep command on that one file.

Some people prefer it this way:

```
$ find . -name '.git' -type d -prune \
     -o -name "*.min.*" -prune \
     -o -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep --color -n -H "$pattern"
```

The `-print0` prints out all of the found files separated by the NULL character. The `xargs -0` will read in that list of files and pass them to the `grep` command. The `-0` tells `xargs` that the file names are NULL separated and not whitespace separated. Some `xargs` will take `--null` instead of the `-0` parameter.

Answer (score 18):

Make sure not to include a trailing slash when you specify the directory to exclude. For example:

Do this:

```
$ grep -r --exclude-dir=node_modules firebase .
```

NOT this:

```
$ grep -r --exclude-dir=node_modules/ firebase .
```

(This answer not applicable to OP, but may be helpful for others who find `--exclude-dir` not to be working -- it worked for me.)

Comment: Absolute paths seem to be a no-no as well. I was searching from root and wanted to avoid `/dev`, `/proc`, `/sys`, etc. `--exclude-dir=/dev` didn't work whereas `--exclude-dir=dev` worked as expected.

Comment: This is because --exclude-dir only matches on basenames. This means that referring to a nested folder won't work either, e.g. --exclude-dir=mydir/node_modules should be --exclude-dir=node_modules. See here: https://superuser.com/a/1096219

Comment: also watch out for typos not only in the trailing slash, but due to grep output eg outputting current dir ./snap/, not putting a dot in the beginning of location when its not a hidden one