# Why is running Python subprocess grep ignoring --exclude-dir flag

Tags: python, command-line, grep, subprocess

When executing this command from the terminal:

```
\grep -inH -r --exclude-dir={node_modules,.meteor,.git} -e test -- /Users/nelsyeung/Sites/foo
```

It outputs the correct results, where it excludes the `--exclude-dir` directories.

The following Python script should theoretically perform the exact same operation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cmd = 'grep -inH -r --exclude-dir={node_modules,.meteor,.git} -e test -- /Users/nelsyeung/Sites/foo'
with Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:
    for l in p.stdout:
        print(l)
```

But the `--exclude-dir` flag seems to be ignored, that is, it also grep from `node_modules`, `.meteor` and `.git`.

**Question:** Why is the above code outputting a different result from just executing the command?

Note that this is more of a theory question than me looking for an alternative fix, since the Python code is basically from a plugin that I'm using where I can only supply flags for the command, and just that, to my surprise, passing in `--exclude-dir` does nothing. If there's something wrong with the code above, do point it out though.

**System info:**

- OS: macOS 10.13.6
- Python: 3.7.0
- grep: (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD (with `--exclude-dir` support)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--exclude-dir={dir1,dir2}` [is expanded to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48372385/190597)

```
--exclude-dir=dir1 --exclude-dir=dir2
```

*by the shell*, not by grep. `Popen` uses `shell=False` by default.

So instead use

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cmd = '''grep -inH -r --exclude-dir=node_modules --exclude-dir=.meteor 
         --exclude-dir=.git -e test -- /Users/nelsyeung/Sites/foo'''
with Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:
    for l in p.stdout:
        print(l)
```

(Note that while using `shell=True` might be another option, it is not preferred because of [security issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3172488/190597).)