# Why does grep make my terminal unreadable when searching for @?

Tags: grep

I'm trying to grep my repo searching for `@` sign to find some e-mail addresses because of [this git issue](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/).

I type `grep -rnw '/my/path' -e '@'` into the terminal and I get:

[image]

Why does it happen?

<sub>P.S. I think there is no sensitive information in the picture, but someone please tell me if you think there is.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you have issues only on files within a .git folder, you might consider excluding it from your recursive grep, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1491543/6309).

```
grep --exclude-dir=".git" -nrw ...
```

On CentOS, the [regular `grep`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/1p/grep/) might not include that option though.

Comment: But it's searching inside .git folder what I actually need to do to find any emails in config.

Comment: @adamczi in config? Then you would need only to grep `.git/config`, not all `.git/` subfolder content.

Comment: That's correct. I could acutally exclude `.git/object`, as I can see it may cause troubles. But it doesn't explain why it crashes my terminal and (here in case of ssh login) I have to quit session, exit terminal and run it back again.

Comment: @adamczi In case of an ssh session, it is probably because the tty cannot handle special characters (as in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79686/7490)

Comment: thanks a lot! I couldn't google it, but it seems it has already been discovered and answered. I have to try `stty sane` + `tput rs1`.